# Spring Security, REST and 403 status

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-security

That is my Spring Security config for a Spring Boot application

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/registration", "/restaurants").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .rememberMe()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

That is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = RestaurantController.REST_URL, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class RestaurantController {
    static final String REST_URL = "/restaurants";
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    RestaurantService restaurantService;

    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public RestaurantTo create(@Valid @RequestBody Restaurant restaurant) {
        log.info("create new restaurant");
        return restaurantService.create(restaurant);
    }
}
```

I try to test RESTful using POSTMAN, a POST-request to "/restaurant".
But I'm getting "403 forbidden". I don't understand - what is a reason?

Comment: Please provide URL value to your post method like `@PostMapping( value = REST_URL, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`

Comment: It didn't help...

Comment: Are you trying to acces `/restaurant` or `/restaurants` . Based on your question it seems like you are accessing `/restaurant` which is not matching with any of the allowed matchers.

Comment: exactly "restaurants"

Comment: @MaksimRybalkin Did you send the CSRF token with your request?

Comment: As dur mentioned , try including CSRF token in your request or disable csrf for the test by adding csrf().disable() to configure(HttpSecurity http)